# update-grub in grml

Tags: grub2, livecd, grml

I converted a machine from a single disk to mdadm RAID1. I did this nearly like it's described in [Raid1 on a running system](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-debian-squeeze-p2).

Before, I tried to make the same changes not within the running system, but in grml. update-grub failed. It complained /dev couldn't be found.

Why is update-grub not possible within a live-cd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to bind-mount `/dev` `/proc` and maybe `/sys` to the chroot. You can use [`grml-chroot`](http://grml.org/online-docs/grml-chroot.8.html) which automatically bind these three directories into your chroot.